# Math cases align being colored as a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color

My cases environment is being colored as a table. I do not want that. Seems `tikz` is causing this, because removing it from document fix, but I use tikz everywhere in my real document.

Is there any other solutions for coloring tables without mess with `cases` environment?

Below the MWE (compiled with LuaLatex)

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green}{pink}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & b  \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    x + y &\le 2 \\
    x - y &\ge 2
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When one removes `\usepackage{tikz}` from your MWE one gets `! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \rowcolors
              {2}{green}{pink}`. True, the cases won't be colored then but is this really what you want to say? Can you provide us with a code which runs when removing `tikz` and substantiates that `tikz` is the culprit?

Comment: Please also remove the `rowcolors`. Since, seems `rowcolors` is being provided by `tikz`.

Comment: Seems is a mix of `[table]` parameter and `rowcolors`, don't know who really provides. Don't know enough about latex internals.

Comment: Yes, if you remove `\rowcolors`, neither the table nor the `cases` environment will be colored. `\rowcolors` can be made work by adding `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}`, i.e. you do not need `tikz` for that.  So if you do not want the cases to be colored, either do not use `\rowcolors`, or just use them locally in the tables you want to color.

Comment: should be used the `xcolor` or `colortbl` or both?

Comment: Note that loading tikz also loads xcolor.  In fact, because it is used by other packages, xcolor should generally be loaded first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read your question as

- you want to color the table and not the cases environment and
- you want to use `tikz`.

This can be accomplished by using `\rowcolors` only locally.

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering\rowcolors{2}{green}{pink}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & b  \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    x + y &\le 2 \\
    x - y &\ge 2
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\usepackage{tikz}` you could also use

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
```

to make the above example compile.

Of course, you can make things more automatic by patching `\begin{table}` etc. but I am not necessarily a fan of these hacks.

Comment: thanks. That is what I was trying to figure out.